# history push with switch doesn't redirect

Tags: reactjs, redirect, rendering, react-router-dom

I'm new to react.
I've used CRA to create my app.

I try to build a smooth full page transition, not only on the component who's rendered as we can do with react-transition-group
To do so, I try to manually redirect when I click on a  tag.

But **only the url is changed** but **the page is not re-rendered...**

I've tried with this.context (undefined), < Redirect >, I red the docs and many articles but couldn't figure out how it can work.

*Here is my code*

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.register();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss';
import history from 'js/core/history.js'

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isRedirecting: false
        }

        this.isRedirecting = false;

        this.taContainer = React.createRef();
    }

    redirectHandler(location) {
        if(location != null && location != undefined && !this.state.isRedirecting) {
            this.setState({isRedirecting: true})
            setTimeout(() => {
                history.push(location);
                this.setState({isRedirecting: false})
            }, 1000)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <div className="inner-app">
                    <BackScene></BackScene>
                    <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <Home {...props} onClick={this.redirectHandler.bind(this)} />} />
                            <Route exact path={'/experiments'} render={(props) => <Experiments {...props} onClick={this.redirectHandler.bind(this)}/>
                            <Route exact path={'/experiments/:cat'} render={(props) => <Experiments {...props} />} />
                            <Route exact path={'/experiments/:cat/:slug'} render={(props) => <SingleProject {...props}  />} />
                            <Route exact path={'/shader'} render={(props) => <ShaderTemplatePage {...props} />} />
                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                    <div className="ta" ref={this.taContainer}>
                        <div className="ta-first"></div>
                        <div className="ta-second"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='home page'>
                <div className="inner-home">
                    <div className="content">
                        <h1 className='title'>Title</h1>
                        <a className='button' onClick={() => {this.props.onClick('/experiments')}}>Get started !<span></span></a>
                        <ul className="socials">
                            <li><a href="#"><i className='icon icon-twitter'></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i className='icon icon-instagram'></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**history.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Comment: Can you please show your index.jsx file? Basically where the <App/> component is rendered

Comment: @LoXatoR I updated my post you can now see it at first

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing `history` object as props to the `<BrowserRouter>` component in the index.jsx file?

```
import history from 'js/core/history.js'
<BrowserRouter history={history}>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it still fail, and while searching for a solution I used that which work properly

`{this.state.isRedirecting ? <Redirect exact to={this.state.location}/> : null}`

inside of the Router tag, Is it clean or some silly fix ?

Comment: Can you link me to the solution?

Comment: here is the link of my App.js on pastebin https://pastebin.com/jrihpPQy Thanks for the help !

Comment: What I am not understanding is that why do you have local state variables like `leavePage`, `enterPage`, `isRedirecting` ? This is why react-router-dom is made. The `history` object acts like a stack to remember the all the actions you have tried defining in your `App` local state. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history. 

I think if you see a tutorial on how to use react-router-dom, it will clear a lot of things

Comment: Well, maybe I haven't been clear from the start. The problem I have is, I want to do an animation when I navigate between urls, but, react-router-dom doesn't let me wait/pause during the routing process, So I try to do it manually.
The `leavePage & enterPage & isRedirecting` is only used for adding/removing css class to animate my content as I wish.
I've watched tutorials on react-router-dom but it's always "too simple" and they don't cover the use I have of it.